# The $n$th term of a certain sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the nth term of this sequence?

$$-1,-2,-3,4,5,6,-7,-8,-9,10,11,12,...$$

I know that $n$-th term of the sequence $-1,2,-3,4,...$ is given by  $n(-1)^n$.

I also know that $n$-th term of the sequence $-1,-2,3,4,-5,-6,...$ is given by $n(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$.

Answer (score 4):

One answer is
$$
(-1)^{\lceil n/3\rceil}n.
$$
If that answer isn't satisfying to you, please describe what sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: I feel like that the OP wanted something more like the second sequence given. You're not wrong, I'm 100% not contesting that, but if you notice you can switch $3$ to $2$ and just get his second sequence ... I feel like that might be the "obvious" solution and he wants something different, if that makes any sense? I actually have been trying to address this exact point - that there's the "obvious solution" - in my forthcoming answer (after I trawl through the OEIS) and I don't know how to phrase it right so sorry if this sounds weird.

Comment: My point is, the OP should describe what sort of solution she or he wants.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: @GregMartin The answer is nice and true. But  I want a solution for the sudents of middle school. They dont know the fucntion"integer part". Is there a solution with use of plus,minus,multiply or divide?

Comment: "integer part" could just be like "chop off the decimal part." It might be a new idea to a middle school student but it's certainly easy for them to comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the main issue in finding the sequence for

$$-1,-2,-3,4,5,6,-7,-8,-9,10,11,12...$$

is really going to boil down to finding a rule $f$ to satisfy $a_n = n \cdot (-1)^{f(n)}$ and give us the desired terms. That much should be evidently clear: the rule $a_n = n$ gives us $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...$, we just need some sort of pattern $f(n)$ to generate the signs, right? Specifically, we're looking for some rule for

$$-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,...$$

I also assume you don't want somewhat roundabout formulas in terms of moduli of numbers or whatever. Sure, they work, but given how the second sequence in the OP was stated I guess something else that *doesn't* boil down to just "three $-1$'s then three $1$'s then repeat". I can't exactly phrase well what I'm saying but oh well, maybe someone can fill out the details. (I'm not saying they're invalid, just probably not desired.) For example, the answer given by Greg Martin:

$$(-1)^{\lceil n/3\rceil}n.$$

100% valid, probably not what you want though.

Anyhow. My dumb ramble aside.

So I played around for a bit with various formulas - the $n(n+1)/2$ in the second sequence of the OP made me think of the sum of the first $n$ numbers but that got me nowhere. So I found an interesting entry on the OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences): https://oeis.org/A130151

This gives the slightly related periodic sequence

$$1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,...$$

(Basically a shift of three of our desired sequence. If we get a definition for this sequence, it should be trivial to modify it for our intended sequence, right?)

Now, the problem ... as you can see from that OEIS entry, our slightly related sequence has similar sorts of "obvious" solutions: a lot of moduli, a lot of trigonometric solutions (which are basically in the same vein as using moduli).

So going by the OEIS, you could define $f(n)$ by any of those formulas  at the OEIS link I guess, replacing "$n$" in the definitions by $n-3$ as necessary to account for the shift. They're "cheating" somewhat since I don't feel they're what you're looking for, but I can't find or think of anything that'd work otherwise. From there, multiply each term in the definition by $n$ and you have a sufficient sequence.

So the short of it - I think (though I cannot prove) you're basically limited to definitions that rely on moduli, floor/ceiling functions, or periodic functions (e.g. sine/cosine). If so, I'd basically just use the answer given by Greg Martin:

$$(-1)^{\lceil n/3\rceil}n.$$

Of course I could also be wrong in the impossibility of this. Or, heck, maybe that answer is sufficient and this ramble was utterly pointless. At the end of the day, the problem is generating the sequence

$$1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,...$$

so if someone can do that using a polynomial in $n$ or something like what you want, then I'm definitely wrong.